# activerecord não está salvando a relação

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

eu tenho uma relação assim no rails

```
class ReducaoZ < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'reducaoz'   
  has_many :aliquotas, foreign_key: 'reducaoz_id', class_name: 'Aliquota', dependent: :delete_all
end


class Aliquota < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'aliquota'

  belongs_to :reducaoz, class_name: 'ReducaoZ'
end
```

e em um dado momento, eu instancio várias aliquotas dentro da redução

```
aliquota = reucao.aliquotas.build
aliquota.basecalculo = aliquota.valor
# outros valores
red.aliquotas << aliquota
```

e quando tento salvar a redução z, o campo `reducaoz_id` não está la. como existe uma restrição para não salvar aliquota sem reducaoz_id, o activerecord lança um erro.
aparentemente está tudo correto, não consigo enxergar o erro. alguem tem alguma idéia do que eu deixei passar?

**Edit**
A sql que o rails tenta executar (junto com o erro) é essa

```
  SQL (23.4ms)  INSERT INTO "aliquota" ("aliquota", "basecalculo", "valor") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["aliquota", "0300"], ["basecalculo", "0.0"], ["valor", "0.0"]]
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "reducaoz_id" violates not-null constraint
: INSERT INTO "aliquota" ("aliquota", "basecalculo", "valor") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"
   (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "reducaoz_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: A pergunta não está suficientemente clara para mim. Tu não consegue dar mais detalhes? Copie pra cá o erro do ActiveRecord.

Comment: O que acontece é que o rails não esta setando a redução na aliquota, fazendo a relação entre eles. O banco não deixa salvar uma alíquota sem uma redução. Adicionei a SQL na pergunta

Comment: A redução já existe no banco de dados?

Comment: ainda não. o `red.save!` salva a redução e depois as aliquotas, mas as aliquotas vem sem o id da redução. O engraçado é que outros modelos fazem a mesma coisa (Nota fiscal -> itens) e consigo salva-los sem problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "reducaoz_id" violates not-null constraint

O `PG` na frente da exceção nos indica que esta exceção foi levantada pelo Postgres (por causa da *constraint* `NOT NULL`) e não diretamente pelo ActiveRecord. Isso significa que tu esqueceu de adicionar

```
validates :reducaoz_id, presence: true
```

---

Porém isto não resolve teu problema.

Tente uma vez trocar

```
aliquota = reucao.aliquotas.build
```

por

```
@reducao = ReducaoZ.find(params[:reducaoz_id]) # esta linha pode mudar (não sei como tu fez)
@aliquota = @reducao.aliquotas.new
```

embora teoricamente seja a mesmo coisa.

Comment: Engraçado que eu acabei de fazer quase a mesma coisa agora. Salvei a redução e então, recarreguei ela do banco antes de insntanciar as aliquotas. Acho que isso parece gambiarra, mas não vejo outra forma.

Comment: @LuizE Não considero gambiarra, sempre faço assim.

Comment: Ah, menos mal então hahahahaha

Comment: @LuizE Que bom que funcionou. =)

Comment: MUITO bom. eu estava emperrado nisso ja fazia uns 2 dias